# Record & Play what comes from the microphone at the same time

Tags: command-line, audio

For a project, I would like to be able to use arecord to do both at the same time :

- Recording what is passed to the microphone.
- Playing it at the same time in the speakers.

In order to do this, I thought about starting with :

```
arecord -f cd -d numberofseconds -t raw | lame -x – out.mp3
```

but I don't know how to redirect at the same time the sound to the speakers. Do you have any idea about how I could do this ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: (1) Use `tee` and a subshell (2) Use `multitee` (3) Use `dshare` plugin and `alsaloop` (4) Use Pulseaudio and `module-loopback`, or both `parec ... | lame ...` and `parec ... | paplay ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I have found :

1. First, enable audio forwarding to speakers with `pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1`
2. Then I record all I want using `arecord -f cd -t raw | oggenc - -r -o out.ogg` (using mp3 format didn't works)
3. To finish, I stop audio forwarding using `pactl unload-module module-loopback`

If you find a way to correctly record as mp3 (using lame) from microphone, don't hesitate to [answer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196534/recording-audio-with-ubuntu-arecord-mp3-files-are-filled-with-static-sound/) and tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple procedure  which worked for me was the following

1. Opened two terminals
2. On one terminal I started recording (from the mic input) with the command

   $ rec a.wav
3. In  the other terminal played the same file

   $ play a.wav

Comment: `rec` command is not found. What is the package or aplication?